# SimpleInjector MediatR scope lost

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, cqrs, simple-injector, mediatr

Within a Blazor server application I do use the Simple Injector integration as well as the MediatR. The Simple Injector looks like it works pretty fine together with Blazor with respect to the scoping, but it breaks once it reaches the mediator and the scope is lost and recreated somehow.

Within the application I created a simple scenario to demonstrate the issue:

The simple idea is I have a scoped service that returns different GUID for every instance so I can track if the instance is still the same. I will invoke the service directly or via the MediatR.

```cs
public interface IScoped { public Guid Id { get; init; } }
public class TestScoped : IScoped {
    public TestScoped() => Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    public Guid Id { get; init; }
}
public interface IScopedCaller {void CallScoped(); }

public class ScopedCaller : IScopedCaller  {
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;
    private readonly IScoped _scoped;

    public ScopedCaller(IMediator mediator, IScoped scoped) {
        _mediator = mediator;_scoped = scoped;
    }
    public void CallScoped() {
        Debug.WriteLine(_scoped.Id);
        _mediator.Send(new TestScopedRequest());
    }
}
public class TestScopedRequest: IRequest{ }

public class TestScopedRequestHandler : IRequestHandler<TestScopedRequest> {
    private readonly IScoped _scoped;

    public TestScopedRequestHandler(IScoped scoped){
        _scoped = scoped;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(TestScopedRequest request, CancellationToken _){
        Debug.WriteLine(_scoped.Id);
        return default;
    }
}
```

If I reference the `IScoped` directly from the application/Blazor pages, I get a correct/expected output across multiple components (the GUID is the same):

[image: GUIDs are the same]

If I invoke the `ScopedCaller.CallScoped()` method, this is what I find in the console:

```
5a7c7871-15d7-4222-bc3f-77e8ab964031
0e10fe5a-8a3d-4b92-bd68-85e904eda187
```

The first (correct) line comes from the `CallScoped()` method directly. The other one - new GUID - comes from the `Handle` method.

It means the handler uses a different instance since it operates in a different scope.

All the registrations in the Simple Injector (including the `Mediator` itself and the RequestHandler) are `Lifestyle.Scoped`.

How can I achieve the same instance is used all the time within the same scope? Singleton would not work for me. I need to ensure that if I run a mediator request from inside a scope, the scope is reused within the mediator too.

Comment: What code/library are you using to integrate Simple Injector with MediatR? This is something I can't see from your question. Can you convert your question into a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so I can code paste your code into a console and debug this myself?

Comment: That asked, the behavior you're seeing is actually something I would expect for a Blazor application, because you certainly don't want your MediatR requests/commands/queries to run inside the same scope as your Blazor page does. A Blazor page and its scope can live for for a very long time. MediatR requests should each have their own scope, not share a scope with possible dozens of other requests.

Comment: @Steven The behavior I would expect here is that everything runs in the same scope unless I explicitly set something different. I worked this around by the solution mentioned below. However, I hit a new one - the scope differs for the component itself and for injected dependencies.

Comment: I'd like to warn you again: you *should not* reuse the Blazor scope in your MediatR request handlers, because Blazor pages (and their scopes) can live for a very long time, causing many request handlers to request the same scope. This can lead to memory issues and causes the data DbContexts cache to become stale.

Comment: I am aware of it. In the case I hit that issue first is the request handler just initiates a background job. It does not hold any problematic resources like DbContext. But what I need is some context/metadata about app state from the scope.

Comment: Actually, your warning is the state I now want to achieve. Not to maintain it in production, but I understand it should be the state. However, what I am getting now is not a single shared scope for the whole application for all components, but multiple scopes created for an unknown (to me) reason. Once I do have really a single Simple Injector scope per the whole SPA, then I know that the setup is technically correct and I can think  about the right architecture/design.

Comment: @Steven Perhaps I have just found the spot that causes the troubles to me: if I call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo` while the navigation target is the same page (and the parameters are set in the URI), then in the `OnParametersSetAsync` the actual container scope is different from what is inherited and set in the scope accessor.
Could you please provide any help with that?
Is the only chance JS workaround?

Comment: Can you provide me with a small Github repo that reproduces this issue?

Comment: Sure, check this out, please: https://github.com/jan-drozen/Blazor-SimpleInjector/tree/example

Comment: Your repro elegantly demonstrates the problem. Thank you for taking the time to create a github repo. Unfortunately, after looking into this, I have no fix for this issue, other than advising to call `NavigateTo` with `forceLoad` set to `true` instead, as in: `NavigateTo($"/fetchdata/{value}", true)`.

Comment: If passing `true` to `NavigateTo` isn't an option, you can opt for using [flowing scopes](https://docs.simpleinjector.org/en/latest/lifetimes.html#flowing-scopes) (a.k.a. the [closure composition model](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/p/ccm)) instead of ambient scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the issue for this particular issue. I was able to reproduce it using a new template project. The problem was I had in my startup config:

```
services.AddSimpleInjector(container, options => {
    options.AddAspNetCore()
       .AddControllerActivation()
       .AddViewComponentActivation();
    options.AddServerSideBlazor(new[] {typeof(Program).Assembly});
})
```

The default behavior of the ASP.NET Core integration caused the issue with scopes - actually nested scoping.

I got rid of it by the flag:

```
 options.AddAspNetCore(ServiceScopeReuseBehavior.OnePerNestedScope)
```